# keytool command successful on command line but not via ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder, keytool

I am trying to use keytool to generate a certificate programmatically. In order to do that, I am first generating a keystore using the following command:

```
-genkeypair -alias alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=name,OU=ou,O=o,c=pt" -validity 365 -keystore teststore.jks -keypass testpass -storepass testpass -noprompt
```

On the command line this completes successfully, creating the file `teststore.jks` without asking for the user's input. I need this since I will be using this command from a `ProcessBuilder` instance.

I use the following code to generate the same command:

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
command.append("keytool ");
command.append("-genkeypair");
command.append(" -keystore " + username + "store.jks");
command.append(" -alias " + username);
command.append(" -keyalg RSA");
command.append(" -keysize 2048");
command.append(" -dname \"CN="+username+", OU=FCT, O=UNL, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=PT\"");
command.append(" -validity " + 365);
command.append(" -keypass " + certpassword);
command.append(" -storepass " + certpassword);
command.append(" -noprompt");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.toString());
pb.inheritIO();
pb.start();
```

When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool -genkeypair -keystore teststore.jks -alias alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=name, OU=ou, O=o, C=pt" -validity 365 -keypass ssc1415 -storepass ssc1415 -noprompt": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at UserRegistry.main(UserRegistry.java:29)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 1 more
```

Since I use `pb.inheritIO()` I commented out the `-dname` and the `-noprompt` parts and it still terminated with the same error, so I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in working around this issue by supplying a `String[]` and using the `getRuntime().exec()` method.
I used:

```
// Generate key for keystore
String userStore = username + "KeyStore.jks";
String userDetails = "CN=" + username
        + ", OU=FCT, O=UNL, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=PT";
String certValidity = "" + 365;
String keytoolArgs[] = { "keytool", "-genkeypair", "-alias",
        username, "-keystore", "Client/" + userStore,
        "-keypass", certpassword, "-storepass", certpassword,
        "-keyalg", "RSA", "-keysize", "2048", "-dname",
        userDetails, "-validity", certValidity };
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(keytoolArgs));
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(keytoolArgs);
p1.waitFor();
```

This enabled me to create a key with dynamic arguments passed in to a program, which in my project made it easier to build multiple certificates at once.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while creating command array in ProcessBuilder you need to specify each not white space argument as a separate command object. White spaces are NOT allowed inside arguments.

For example this will not work

```
command.append(" -alias " + username);
```

This should be written as (also the value should be a separate argument)

```
command.append("-alias");
command.append(username);
```

Please try with this code

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
command.append("keytool");
command.append("-genkeypair");
command.append("-keystore");
command.append(username);
command.append("store.jks");
command.append("-alias");
command.append(username);
command.append("-keyalg");
command.append("RSA");
command.append("-keysize");
command.append("2048");
command.append("-dname");
command.append("CN="+username+",OU=FCT,O=UNL,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=PT");
command.append("-validity");
command.append("365");
command.append("-keypass");
command.append(certpassword);
command.append("-storepass");
command.append(certpassword);
command.append("-noprompt");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.toString());
```

Comment: The command string which comes out after command.toString(), doesn't contain ne spaces. So we have to do extra command.append(" "); after every  command.append("keytool");. Also the  StringBuilder removes quotes. Other option of doing the same is using String array. String[] commands = { cmdPath, "-genkeypair","-keyalg", "RSA","-keysize", "2048", "-keystore", username, "-alias",  userName, "-dname",  "CN="+username+",OU=FCT,O=UNL,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=PT", "-validity", "365", "-keypass", passwd, "-storepass", passwd,"-noprompt"}; 
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);